# boost optional and user-defined conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, type-conversion

I am unable to write a correct user defined conversion for a type `Item`. This is what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct Item
{
    boost::optional<int> x_;

    Item(){}
    Item(const A& s)
    : x_(s.x)
    {
    }

    operator boost::optional<A>() const {
        boost::optional<A> s;
        if (x_) {
            s->x = *x_;
        }
        return s;
    }
};

std::vector<A> getA(const std::vector<Item> &items) {
    std::vector<A> a;
    for (const auto &i : items) {
        if (i.x_) {
            a.push_back(*static_cast<boost::optional<A>>(i));  // <- this line causes error
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

That is how I use it:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    a.x = 3;
    Item i(a);
    auto v = getA({i});

    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++11` says:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/optional.hpp:15:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct(const Expr&, const void*) [with Expr = Item; T = A]’:
/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:262:25:   required from ‘boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::optional_base(const Expr&, const Expr*) [with Expr = Item; T = A]’
/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:559:78:   required from ‘boost::optional<T>::optional(const Expr&) [with Expr = Item; T = A]’
test.cpp:30:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:392:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(const Item&)’
        new (m_storage.address()) internal_type(expr) ;
        ^
/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:392:8: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:3:8: note: A::A()
 struct A
        ^
test.cpp:3:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr A::A(const A&)
test.cpp:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Item’ to ‘const A&’
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr A::A(A&&)
test.cpp:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Item’ to ‘A&&’
```

Why does it try to find `A` struct constructor instead of use user defined conversion operator?

You may point me directly to any position of the [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) page because I am unable to find any reason for this. For example,

> User-defined conversion function is invoked on the second stage of the implicit conversion, which consists of zero or one converting constructor **or** zero or one user-defined conversion function.

in my opinion directly says that if no conversion constructor is defined then user-defined conversion function will be used. Am I wrong? And if yes, how can I implement user-defined conversion then without defining conversion cunstructor in `struct A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with your code. Your `optional` operator never initializes the `boost::optional`. If you don't do that, accessing members is undefined behavior. What you have to do is:

```
operator boost::optional<A>() const {
    boost::optional<A> s;
    if (x_) {
        s = A{*x_};
    }
    return s;
}
```

The second issue is when you do:

```
static_cast<boost::optional<A>>(i);
```

That is equivalent to:

```
boost::optional<A> __tmp(i);
```

But it turns out that [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_constructor_factory) has an `explicit` template constructor. That will be preferred to your conversion function. The error you're seeing is the compiling going down the path of this factory constructor, where `Item` is not such a factory.

You could simply use `boost::optional<A>` directly:

```
std::vector<A> getA(const std::vector<Item> &items) {
    std::vector<A> a;
    for (boost::optional<A> opt : items) {
        if (opt) {
            a.push_back(*opt);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Or, since the constructor template is `explicit`, you could use the conversion operator in a non-explicit context:

```
boost::optional<A> opt = i;
a.push_back(*opt);
```

This has the added benefit of also being easier to read.

Comment: Oops, while moving the code for testing forgot to initialize it, thanks. About the actual answer - what if I need to check some fields or just do something with the `Item` object before converting it to `boost::optional<A>` ? Your answer uses `boost::optional<A>` right from the beginning however I want to do that later after some work with `Item`.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Updated with the cause of the `static_cast` error.